# How to install SFML in ubuntu?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, installation, sfml

I downloaded SFML, then I copied all its headers in **usr/local/include/** and copied all its libraries in **usr/local/lib/** .

I have a file named **main.cpp** in Desktop which I want to compile.

First I did this :-

```
g++ -c main.cpp
```

After that when I try to do this :-

```
g++ main.o -o sfml-app -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

It gives me :-

```
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_action@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_list_entry_get_next@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_unref@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_list_entry_get_name@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_unref@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_unref@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_new@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_receive_device@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)@GLIBCXX_3.4.20'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_devnode@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_enable_receiving@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_new@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_get_fd@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_unref@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_property_value@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_filter_add_match_subsystem_devtype@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_get_list_entry@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_scan_devices@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_syspath@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysattr_value@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_new_from_netlink@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_new_from_syspath@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_parent_with_subsystem_devtype@LIBUDEV_183'
```

I have installed all these required dependencies correctly :
https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Installing-SFML-dependencies

Have I missed any required step ?

Comment: change `main.o` to `main.cpp`

Comment: see http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=18187.0 for std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt.

Comment: You are compiling C++ code, so should use `g++` instead of `gcc`. This will link to the C++ standard library for you.

Comment: @liya Popov I have already tried both. Both of them are showing these errors.

Answer (score 9):

To Install it in Ubuntu first you run following command in your terminal -

```sh
sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev
```

make sure you already have compiler (GCC) and make if not then install it using

```sh
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Then to test this out create a simple SFML app like this

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200,200), "Hello From SFML");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Magenta);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed){
                window.close();
            }
        }
        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now create a `makefile` in the repo same as `main.cpp`

```
compile:./main.cpp
    g++ -c ./main.cpp
    g++ main.o -o app -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

run:
    ./app
```

now to compile it run the following command

```sh
make compile
```

and finally to run this run following command

```sh
make run
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because you're got the dependencies installed doesn't mean you're making use of them.

```
undefined reference to `udev_device_get_action@LIBUDEV_183'
```

The mention of `udev` and `LIBUDEV` suggest to me that you need to link against libudev. Try adding `-ludev` to your command line.

If you pasted all of the link errors, then that might actually take care of it. If you just pasted the first 20, then there might be other libraries that need to be linked in. Look at the missing symbols, figure out what libraries they're from, and add them.

```
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)@GLIBCXX_3.4.20'
```

Not sure what the deal is there. You might need to link against the C++ libraries?

Anyways, you should take a look at the instructions for setting up makefiles for your SFML project: https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Build-your-SFML-project-with-CMake